# Software center not opening on Ubuntu 13.04 due to Gdk-ERROR

Tags: software-center

I know there's a lot of other questions about similar problems, but my error seems different from the others. (Apologies if I actually missed the one that addresses mine)

When I open Software Center I get this error. I tried to remove it (`apt-get remove --purge software-center` and re-installed it, but the error remained). What is wrong?  I thought it could be something related to Gnome, so I changed to Unity, but the problem still occurs. I am running Ubuntu 13.04.

```
013-10-15 18:13:49,317 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-10-15 18:13:49,626 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-10-15 18:13:49,628 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2013-10-15 18:13:49,634 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2013-10-15 18:13:49,634 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2013-10-15 18:13:49,659 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2013-10-15 18:13:50,937 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/utils.py', 271, 'get_title_from_html')'
2013-10-15 18:13:50,937 - root - WARNING - failed to parse: '<div style="background-color: #161513; width:1680px; height:200px;">
 <div style="background: url('/site_media/exhibits/2013/09/AAMFP_Leaderboard_700x200_1.jpg') top left no-repeat; width:700px; height:200px;"></div>
</div>' ('ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 70: ordinal not in range(128))

(software-center:5947): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'software-center' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 2420 error_code 9 request_code 62 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Comment: That's a bug Jonny.

Comment: Yep seems so. I was on the wrong track thinking I messed something up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems it is actually a known bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1163886

There is a hack which involves commenting out a line described in the bug report which basically is this:

`self.exhibit_banner.set_exhibits([FeaturedExhibit()])`

inside the file:

`/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py`

ugly, but works.